# How move camera where i look?

Tags: unity, c#

I am try make simple flying camera. Without character. But than I press forward camera moving to another direction.

```
    void Update()
{
    horizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    verticalInput   = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

    var mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    var mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

    var trm = Camera.main.transform;

    if (horizontalInput != 0 || verticalInput != 0)
    {
        trm.position += moveSpeed * new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0, verticalInput);
    }

    var rotateValue = new Vector3(mouseY * 2, mouseX * -2, 0);

    trm.eulerAngles -= rotateValue;

    //trm.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotateValue);
}
```

[image]

Than I press 'W' camera moving  to left... I understand that it is necessary to coordinate the motion vectors and camera rotation. How best to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Transform.transformDirection()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformDirection.html).

```
if (horizontalInput != 0 || verticalInput != 0)
{
    Vector3 vec = moveSpeed * new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0, verticalInput);
    trm.position += trm.transformDirection(vec);
}
```

It basically converts a vector direction from the transform's local space into world space. So that transform's rotation is going to affect that vector.

Comment: Can you answer to another question. How to rotate the camera around the axis of look direction.